# ros_canopen reset encoders?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Is it possible in `ros_canopen` somehow (e.g., through service call) to reset the encoder/position values?

I mean:

the robot performs different movements, then

the robot is actuated to a particular pose,

and hereafter i want to make that particular pose the **new home** (0,0,0,0,0) pose of the robot.

What would be the workaround?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312493/ros_canopen-reset-encoders?/) by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2019-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can reset poses during CANopen homing (e.g. mode 35).
However, there is no service call to trigger homing again (https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/227).

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2019-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0